# GeoTools: how to set display extent (bounds) JMapFrame

Tags: java, bounds, geotools

I would like to set display extent on JFrameMap

```
List<SimpleFeature> features = new ArrayList<SimpleFeature>();

GeometryFactory gf = JTSFactoryFinder.getGeometryFactory();

Point point1 = gf.createPoint(new Coordinate(2,3));
Point point2 = gf.createPoint(new Coordinate(4,2));

SimpleFeatureBuilder fb = new SimpleFeatureBuilder(TYPE);

SimpleFeature f;

fb.add(point1);
fb.add("TP-1");

f = fb.buildFeature(null);
features.add(f);

fb.add(point2);
fb.add("TP-2");

f = fb.buildFeature(null);
features.add(f);

SimpleFeatureCollection collection = new ListFeatureCollection(TYPE,features);

Style style = createPointStyle();

Layer layer1 = new FeatureLayer(collection, style);

layer1.setTitle("TEST Map Layer"); 

MapContent map = new MapContent();
map.setTitle("Floor Map");
map.addLayer(layer1);

JMapFrame.showMap(map);
```

It display my points but I do not like the automatic extent (bounds) set.
Question is how I can change it ?

Answer (score 1):

you can set the viewport bounds to anything you like:

```
 JMapFrame frame = new JMapFrame(map);
 frame.getMapPane().getMapContent().getViewport().setBounds(envelope);
```

where envelope is a ReferencedEnvelope.